# Confusion with the partial derivative of a natural logarithm

Tags: logarithms, partial-derivative

Why do we solve the following example using chain rule? I would assume that the answer would be $18/x^1$.

[image]

Comment: What are $f$ and $g$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have to. The second equality is essentially this:

$$
\frac{d}{dx}\left(9(\ln x)^2\right)=9\cdot 2\ln x \cdot\frac{d}{dx}\ln(x)
=\frac{18\ln x}{x}
$$

[Edited:] From the context of your identities, $\ln^2x:=(\ln x)^2$.

Also, the superscripts on $x^1$ and $x^2$ mean different components, not exponents.

Comment: It depends on the author., $\ln^2(x)$ might also mean $\ln(\ln(x))$

Comment: Sure. Edited. Thanks.